# comparing two attr with values

Tags: jquery, attr

I am trying to get the math for this, probably missing something simple.  It should spit out the dis - loc, but I get NaN. Here is my code.

Jquery

```
console.log("-----" +$('.images').attr('dis') - $('.images').attr('loc')
                         );
```

I realize I could put these into a var, but this needs to run on possibly 30 images.

```
 <img style="left: -195px; height: 882px;" class="images" speed-racer="55" src="-------/assets/img/fwman/FeeneyMan_bike.png" loc="300px" dis="-140">
```

I have to keep the HTML covert, is why I didnt want to share it.. But thanks for the -2 =p

/--------------------------------------------------/
Thank you all for your input, the final code worked properly.

```
  $('.images').each(function () {
      speed_racer = $(this).attr('speed-racer');
      $(this).css({
          left: "+=" + (parseFloat($('.images').attr('dis')) - parseFloat($('.images').attr('loc')) / parseFloat($('.images').attr('dis'))
      )
  });
```

Comment: can we see your html?

Comment: Can you please share your html anyway ?

Comment: If you are trying to do numerical substraction, try to convert them to number first by using "number($('.images').attr('dis'))". If you can provide the html as well, we would be able to help a lot better.

Comment: Those guys are all wrong. You said that you've 30 images. So `$('.images')` is an array of objects. See my answer, this will work for you.

Comment: hey cam. why not say that you need 2 keep html clean from the start?? this would have reduced the flame. also the snippet you added now isn't really helpful :( furthermore one does not brag about votes, but hey. you shouldn't be so new to this right? and actually it is -3/ +1

Comment: Can you try adding "data-" to your attributes?

Comment: dis and loc are dynamically written by other jquery script.

Comment: Doesn't matter if `data-` is in front of it. All those answers beside mine don't care about the fact that jquery returns multiple results.

Comment: $('.images').each(function(){
                    $(this).attr('dis', $(this).offset().left);
                });

Comment: $('.images').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('loc', $(this).css('left'));
  });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `parseFloat` & brackets carefully.

```
console.log("-----" + (parseFloat($('.images').attr('dis')) - parseFloat($('.images').attr('loc'))));
```

EDIT:

Difference between parseFloat & parseInt (asked by OP) with an example:

```
parseFloat("1.02") = 1.02 //includes decimal
parseInt("1.02") = 1 //ignores digits after decimal point
```

Comment: @cam obviously the datatype of the return... one returns a floating point number, while the other one returns a floored whole number

Comment: THat worked, A explanation of the parseFloat would be great, I am unfamiliar with this, as I am getting into more Mathematical calculations it would be of great benefit.

Comment: parseFloat returns a floating point number. parseInt returns an integer. parseInt allows you to (and you should) specify a radix value to determine the number base to use.

Comment: parseFloat("1.02") = 1.02 & parseInt("1.02") = 1. If you care about accurate subtractions with decimals, you need parseFloat

Comment: I have high hopes of avoiding the decimal pitfall, but this worked. Now I know how parseFloat works will help in the future.

Comment: @Cam - great. glad to help. please upvote all helpful answers & accept one as an answer.

Comment: @Krishna already upvoted everyone, I really appreciate the community involvement on this answer!

Answer (score 3):

Try it like this. Note the extra `( )`

```
console.log("-----" + ($('.images').attr('dis') - $('.images').attr('loc')));
```

I think the reason is because you are adding a string to a number and then you are subtracting them both.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to actually convert those string values to integers using `parseInt()` or `parseFloat()`?

```
var value = parseInt($('.images').attr('dis')) - parseInt($('.images').attr('loc'));
console.log("-----" + value);
```

Comment: Generally, with parseInt, you need to include the radix value. So parseInt(thingToParse, 10) for base10 integers.

Comment: javascript can dynamically covert; no need to parseInt if the expressions are separated

Comment: Dynamic conversion is javascript's best guess, and in my experience, it guesses wrong a lot. My view is never to leave it to change. Be explicit about what you want it to do, unless you are willing to accept javascript's best guess.

Answer (score 1):

Because you have approx 30 images on your site `$('.images').attr('dis')` will have multiple results. So you'll have to use a foreach like:

```
$('.images').each(function(){
  console.log(parseFloat($(this).attr('dis')) - parseFloat($(this).attr('loc')));
})
```

Comment: Jurik, I have that already written in, but thank you for your input I appreciate it.

Comment: Good, voted up your question, but still -2 - I hate it when **** downvote before thinking.

Comment: Its ok, its cause I didnt want to post HTML, sometimes I am concerned answers get to complicated with adding too much information.

Answer (score 0):

Aren't those supposed to be data attributes ?

```
console.log("-----" +$('.images').attr('data-dis') - $('.images').attr('data-loc'));
```